# help, can't empty my trash folder on external hdd

Tags: delete, trash

I've been searching for this problem on the webs but none of the solutions i've found worked for me.
The problem is that I have an external hard drive and the trash folder won't delete.

the complete path of the problem folder:

/media/Elements/.. .Trash-1000/expunged/2969272896

For some reason if i just press delete when that folder is selected it delete's as a normal folder, but it will always reappear.
Deleting the folder in windows won't work either.

There are no files in the folder.

Comment: please add (from terminal) the result of the command `ls -ld` applied to every component of the path... like `ls -ld /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/expunged/2969272896`, `ls -ld /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/expunged/` etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the trash has nothing else important in it:

```
rm -rf /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/
```

You may want to try as root as well:

```
sudo rm -rf /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/
```

Another method would be to use `srm` - it would wipe over the data and remove it. It also shows if it is a hardlink etc.

If you need to install it:

```
 sudo apt-get install secure-delete
```

and then

```
srm -rf /media/Elements/.Trash-1000/
```

Comment: What if I want to delete only specific files from the trash? Is there any utility to do it correctly or do I have to manually delete the file from both trash subdirectories `files` and `info` (anything else apart that?)?

Comment: Never mind, I have found it. There's a package `trash-cli` that contains several commands for the proper trash management that handles common operations (delete to trash, restore, empty, list, remove from trash).