# What is the official way of emptying the "Bin" of an external hard disk?

Tags: 20.04, files, filemanager, delete

I deleted a large directory on an external disk. Well, actually, I clicked the "Move to Bin", since there is no "Delete" menu. Anyway, I tried to empty the bin, but the bin icon on the desktop was empty and could not be emptied. I researched and saw [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/403515/470399), but that was deleting the hidden directory with `sudo rm -rf`. Is this the indented method for emptying the bin? If it is the only way, I will use that but,... did the Ubuntu developers actually want average people to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't delete items from trash on additional harddrive.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/945536/cant-delete-items-from-trash-on-additional-harddrive)

Comment: @user535733 So, we are supposed to delete the hidden directory manually to empty the bin on an external drive?

Comment: Well, it depends upon how that hard drive is formatted, which desktop environment you are using, and perhaps other factors, too. When I plug one of my external drives in to my system, I am able to use the Trash normally on it. But we don't know how your system and your components are different from mine.